# Atmosphere: How to get logged in user from webSocket connection in Grails?

Tags: grails, spring-security, websocket, atmosphere

I am working on bringing WebSockets functionality to my Grails application. I use Atmosphere Meteor plugin 0.7.1 for this purpose.
The workflow is simple:

- User logs in the system.
- User open page with WebSockets functionality
- User clicks a Connect button to establish the connection... **and the server doesn't recognize him.**

I would like to know which user connected my webSocket.

Usually it's quite easy to detect current user by calling `springSecurityService.getPrincipal()` in any controller. I managed to inject `springSecurityService` to my MeteorHandler, however it says that the principal is `null`. It feels strange for me, as the handler has access to `JSESSIONID` cookie, so I expect it to retrieve the correct session data.

Also, `request.session` command returns different HttpSession object, compared to the same command performed in regular controller action.

So is there any way to retrieve current logged in user on webSockets connection?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Principal object could be easily retrieved from `request.userPrincipal.principal`

It is exactly the same object as in `springSecurityService.getPrincipal()`

Find more here: https://github.com/kensiprell/grails-atmosphere-meteor/issues/28#issuecomment-34629462